# jQuery calls after HTML DOM selectors has been updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, dom

When the document is ready, I am preparing click functions to some of the elements in such a way:

```
var divs = $("div a");
divs.click(function(){
  alert("clicked");

  return false;
});


var spans = $("span a");
spans.click(function(){
  $("div").append("<a>Another link</a>");
  alert("done");

  return false;
});
```

As you can notice, when user clicks on a link inside a `<span>`, I am appending new anchor into `<div>` element with *append()* function.

**And than, when I click on those, just appended new anchors inside** `<div>`**, I am not getting** `alert("clicked")`**, which has to be?!** But when clicking on default anchors, which hasn't been appended, alert still works for them?!

---

Than I am changing the code wrapping first part into a function:

```
function activateClick(){
  var divs = $("div a");
  divs.click(function(){
    alert("clicked");

    return false;
  });
}

// calling a function when page has been loaded
// to allow clicking on default anchors
activateClick();

var spans = $("span a");
spans.click(function(){
  $("div").append("<a>Another link</a>");

  // calling a function when new anchors appended
  activateClick();
  alert("done");

  return false;
});
```

And at the end, new anchors, which has been appended into `<div>`, are giving an `alert("clicked")`, but **those default ones, gives this alert() more than one time**, depends on how many times I have been called a function?!

**Why so?! I need that always one alert appear!**

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here so it works on anchors created later:

```
$("div a").live("click", function(){
  alert("clicked");    
  return false;
});

$("span a").click(function(){
  $("div").append("<a>Another link</a>");
  alert("done");
  return false;
});
```

If you always have that one `<div>`, then use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead, which is a bit cheaper, like this:

```
$("div").delegate("a", "click", function(){
  alert("clicked");    
  return false;
});
```

Comment: @Nikita: Or hook them up after you create them, whichever fits your needs better. `live` is usually the better choice when you're dealing with adding/removing elements, but it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spans = $("span a");

spans.click(function(){
  var __a = $("<a>Another link</a>").appendTo("div");
  __a.click(function() {
      alert("clicked");
      return false;
  });
  alert("done");
  return false;
});
```